# Why does my texture image look compressed in the z direction on the side of this cylinder, but look perfect on the top?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I have UV unwrapped my cylinder, and applied all transformations to the object, but I still get distortion on the side wall of my cylinder when I apply a texture image. I thought maybe this was simply because the cylinder's polygons are not actually square, so I tried scaling them in the UV editor but it didn't seem to do anything. I scaled them in the z direction in the scene as well just to see what would happen, but it made no difference. I also messed with the shader options. Changing my texture image mapping to Box helped a lot, before I did that the stretching/compression was much worse. I'm probably missing something rather simple, any help would be appreciated. I know there are other threads about this as well and I read through them and tried the suggested solutions but was unsuccessful.
[image]

[image: Shader Editor for reference]

[image: UV Unwrap and Scene for reference]

Comment: You're using _Generated_ coordinates, which are 3D, and measure 0->1 in all dimensions of the object's bounding box. Shouldn't you be using _UV_ coordinates, to pick up the UV Map?

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for the quick response. What you are saying makes perfect sense to me, but... when I use UV coordinates it gets worse. But because you made that suggestion I tried the other options too, if I use object coordinates and pick my cylinder it comes out perfect!

Comment: Have you applied scale to your cylinder in object mode?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't totally understand it, the solution seemed to be to change the texture coordinate to object, and select my cylinder as the target. :)

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

In your nodetree the mapping input is connected to "generated", so UVs are not playing any role.

If you connect to UV instead, you will be able to manipulate loc, rot scale in the UV editor and reach any trasformation needed.